# SOQL query stopped working, why?

Tags: soql, query, service-cloud-console, servicecloud

I had this query that was working fine, but then I needed to add some more fields and I get the error message:

> There was an error when retrieving the Salesforce field information for the object or object query provided. Error: field 'First_reply_time__c' was not found for object 'Case'.

I don't know what might be causing this and how to solve it.

[image: Query]

Answer (score 0):

When using the query API, Salesforce enforces field level security just like if you ran the query on the console within the org. The user you ran the query with probably does not have access to that field on the case.

Check the field level permissions for the profile of the user that you ran the query with and try again.